# Add margin depending on image height

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce-theming

I am developing this page here - http://freesamples.charitycards.org/.

Where the images are shorter I'd like to add margin-bottom so that the card details are pushed down closer to the button.

I've tried the following code which seems to work on a JS fiddle I did but not on the live site.

```
if ($('.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail').outerHeight() < 160) {
  $('.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail').css('margin-bottom', '81px');
}
```

If anyone could help me with this that would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: you could do it with pure css. Try `vertical-align:bottom; display: flex;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did try that but couldn't get it to work, on what element would you use that CSS? Could you give me an example of the CSS you'd use?

Answer (score 0):

Set min height on your class in css like ..

```
img.attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail.size-woocommerce_thumbnail {
  min-height: 177px;
}
```

Make sure, if you want to restrict it to any page only then restrict this style with that page id.

Comment: that would stretch the shorter images, I'd like to keep the image sizes as they are